# Is it kosher to accept your answer on your own question?

Tags: discussion, questions, accepted-answer

I've on occasion come across the answer to my [question](https://superuser.com/questions/203186/laptop-battery-technology), and feel that it's the best answer, but do not want to "rob" anyone of rightfully earned rep... What do I do?  Also I'm assuming that I do NOT receive rep for my acceptance of my own answer.

Comment: Accept gives 15 rep, upvote 10 rep (iirc). If you appreciate an answer, even it's not **the** answer, can't you just upvote it?

Comment: Also, just to confirm, you do not recieve the +15 rep for being the accepted answer nor the +2 rep for doing the accepting when you tick your own answer. However, if others upvote an answer you've made on your own question you *will* recieve any rep from those votes as usual. I think you can also recieve bounty rep on your own questions, but only if it is someone else who is providing the bounty.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes it is, but generally I recommend you gives others at least 24 or 48 hours to try and get an answer in.

Who knows? Perhaps someone else even has a better answer, but they might be scared away if you already provided and accepted one!

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing wrong with accepting your own answer as such I've done it [before](https://superuser.com/questions/47875/itunes-limitations-with-respect-to-filetypes). The caveats being

- If you're going to answer your own question - it would be wise to leave a comment stating the same lest someone gets offended ( I'm not saying they will )
- Wait for a while before posting - as Ivo mentioned - who knows! Somebody might come with a better solution!