# What to do if I ask a question but discover the solution myself before anyone else?

Tags: discussion, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it kosher to accept your answer on your own question?](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1621/is-it-kosher-to-accept-your-answer-on-your-own-question)

Recently I asked a question about Outlook Express crashing. Someone left an answer with a possible reason and a list of steps to do in case that was it. Turns out that wasn't it, and I discovered the reason myself while waiting for people to answer.

What should I do now? Leave the question unanswered and leave the answerer a comment? Answer it myself and accept that answer?

Comment: Duplicate over at SO-Meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions

Comment: `Answer it myself and accept that answer?` - Yes - refer to the Duplicate link for more details