# Click handling on post preview inconsistent and confusing

Tags: bug, editing, javascript

How Super User (and probably all Stack Exchange sites) handle clicks to preview areas for posts currently being written is confusing and horribly inconsistent:

- **If I click the preview pane for a new answer...**

  The page focuses on the associated answer text area, i.e. the input field that is used as source for the preview I just clicked.

  *Very useful for longer posts, especially in topics with several answers, since it makes finding the text field trivially easy*.
- **If I click the preview pane for an existing post I'm editing inline...**

  Nothing happens. The current text area loses focus.
- **If I click the preview pane for a [Q&A style answer](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/4882/answer-your-own-question-surely-you-jest-what-next-fix-my-own-plumbing) written parallel to the question...**

  The page focuses on the text area *for the question?!*

  *Surely you jest! What's next, focusing the search box?*

Answer (score 3):

### Observation:

I'm fairly certain this has to do with the `tabindex` attribute. When you click a post's preview pane (`<div class="wmd-preview">`), the focus jumps to the an input box (`<textarea class="wmd-input">`) with `tabindex="101"`. Unfortunately, this does not always match up with the correct element.

Going in the same order as above:

1. The answer's input box has a `tabindex` of `101`. Clicking the preview pane moves the focus correctly.
2. The question and answer both have a `tabindex` of `81`. Clicking the preview pane moves the focus to `tabindex="101"`. This element doesn't exist, so focus is lost!
3. The question has a `tabindex` of `101`. The answer has one of `103`. Clicking the preview for either moves the focus to the question's input box.

I tried to change the `tabindex` for cases 2 and 3 after the page loaded, but it made no difference. I suspect that the `tabindex` is only used in a condition when pairing a preview pane to an input box. That is, once the elements are paired via JavaScript, then the `tabindex` has no meaning.

Comment: Not the first time `tabindex` broke something. It's also the cause of completely useless tab navigation once multiple inline editors are visible...