# Which answer to accept: best for me, or best in general?

Tags: discussion, questions, accepted-answer

I asked [a question](https://superuser.com/questions/1179758/how-can-i-send-a-notification-to-a-windows-10-computer-from-the-command-line) a few days ago which I subsequently found my own answer to. I gather that [accepting your own answer](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1621/is-it-kosher-to-accept-your-answer-on-your-own-question) is fine, however in this case I feel that whilst my answer solves it *for me*, in general the current top answer is more useful to the community at large. As such, I'm not sure about which answer to accept.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What worked for you. Especially where it's a detailed, unique answer. Unless you feel another answer is awesome and you tested it.

It's not cool to copy/slightly modify an existing answer or worse "x's answer worked" as an answer but here, I see nothing wrong with picking your own.

Answer (score 0):

As Journeyman Geek noted, the correct answer is the one that worked for you.

That does not mean the other answers should be ignored, and you can upvote and comment that you like other answers too. But you should also note how and why they didn't work.

SU is about **Specific Questions getting Specific Answers**, the correct answer is the one that works for Your Situation. It may be worthwhile determining WHY your question attracted good but inapplicable answers:

- Was your wording ambiguous?
- Did you add ALL the detail necessary?
- What parts might be most easily misunderstood?
- How can I clarify those parts?

Read your own question over a couple times. Try to take yourself out of your own context so you can spot what is in your own mind that is not yet in the question. Add details and specifics. Make sure the program name and version and the OS version are included. Did you include what was going on before the problem started, accurately describe the problem, detail how the actual outcome is different from what you expect? Did you research the issue first yourself and try some solutions? What happened?

All this is helpful context that clarifies the actual problem, allowing the knowledge we bring to your answer to be more narrowly and accurately applied.

There will always be answers that don't quite hit the mark. Some people don't read the question. Some people misunderstand. Some people make some assumptions of their own. But, change what you can to make sure that, as much as possible, the missed marks are not because you failed to convey the details of the problem as clearly as possible.